# node-gyp configure will Error: spawn EPERM at VisualStudioFinder

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017, npm-install, node-gyp

```
C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\test\d-api>node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@16.20.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.0 found at "C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn EPERM
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at execFile (node:child_process:331:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2017OrNewer (C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.0\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:141:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio (C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.0\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:63:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at findVisualStudio (C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.0\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:13:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.0\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:87:9
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:192:23)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\test\d-api
gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author.
```

```
C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\test\d-api>npm config list
; "global" config from C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc

; msvs_version = "2017" ; overridden by user

; "user" config from C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\.npmrc

msbuild_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
msvs_version = "2017"
python = "C:\\Users\\Jenny_Hung\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; node version = v16.20.0
; npm local prefix = C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\test\d-api
; npm version = 8.19.4
; cwd = C:\Users\Jenny_Hung\test\d-api
; HOME = C:\Users\Jenny_Hung
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

When I use npm install sqlite3 or appmetrics-dash and so on.
It always said Error: spawn EPERM and like there is some problem with VisualStudio?
But I installed VisualStudio 2017, and I try node-gyp configure then got the same error.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and turns out it was the ForcePoint or Bitdefender software my company was using that was preventing the launch of Windows's powershell application even for administrators